# Codeigniter set_value

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I make it so that when I go through with error validation on my post form, it doesn't only send back the default values from the database, but if I were to edit the values and hit submit, it would save the data I tried to update with. I'm stuck where I can only do one or the other.

```html
 
<? if (isset($update)) { ?>
<?php echo set_value ('fname'); ?>
<?= form_open("Phonebook/updateentry/" . $entry['id']) ?>
<?= form_fieldset("Update Entry"); ?>
<?= form_label('First Name: ', 'fname'); ?> <br>
<?= form_input(array('name' => 'fname', 'id' => 'fname', 'value' =>  $entry['fname'])); ?> <br> 

<?= form_label('Last Name: ', 'lname'); ?> <br>
<?= form_input(array('name' => 'lname', 'id' => 'lname', 'value' => $entry['lname'])); ?> <br>
<?= form_label('Phone Number: ', 'phone'); ?> <br>
<?= form_input(array('name' => 'phone', 'id' => 'phone', 'value' => $entry['phone'])); ?> <br>
<?= form_label('Email: ', 'email'); ?> <br>
<?= form_input(array('name' => 'email', 'id'=>'email', 'value' => $entry['email'])); ?> <br>
<?= form_submit('phonebooksubmit', 'Submit'); ?>
<?= form_fieldset_close(); ?>
<?= form_close() ?>
<? } ?>
```

```html
private function display()
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM phonebook ORDER BY id ASC;");
  $this->TPL['listing'] = $query->result_array();
  
  $this->load->view('phonebook_view', $this->TPL);
 }
  
   public function updateentry($id)
 {

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required|alpha|min_length[5]|max_length[15]',
  array(
   'required' => 'You have not provided the %s. ',
   'alpha' => '%s must only compose of alphanumeric letters.',
   'max_length' => 'You exceeded max char of 20 . ',
   'min_length' => 'The min length must be 5 . '

  ));
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required|alpha|min_length[5]|max_length[20]',
  array(
   'required' => 'You have not provided %s .',
   'alpha' => '%s must only compose of alphanumeric letters.',

   'max_length' => 'You exceeded max char of 20 . ',
   'min_length' => 'The min length must be 5 . '
  ));
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone Number', 'required|regex_match[/^([0-9]{3})[-. ]([0-9]{4})$/]',
  array(
   'required' => 'You have not provided %s .',
   'regex_match' => 'Please use the correct phone format.'
  ));
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email',
  array(
   'required' => 'You have not provided %s .',
   'valid_email' => 'Please provide valid email. '
  ));
  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class = "errorlist">' , '</p>');
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
   
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM phonebook where id = '$id';");
   $this->TPL['entry'] = $query->result_array()[0];

   
   $this->TPL['update'] = true;
   $this->TPL['memory'] = true;
 
   $this->display();
  }
  else
  { 
  
  $fname = $this->input->post("fname");
      $lname = $this->input->post("lname");
       $phone = $this->input->post("phone");
       $email = $this->input->post("email");      
       $query = $this->db->query("UPDATE phonebook " .
                              "SET fname = '$fname'," .
                              "    lname = '$lname'," .
                              "    phone = '$phone'," .
                              "    email = '$email'" .
                              " WHERE id = '$id';");  
  $this->display();
 }
}
```

I know I have to use the set_value() but i'm not sure how to make it so that it can do both.

Answer (score 0):

set_value has a second parameter, which is the default. In the case of you pulling up records and editing them, it looks like this:

```
// $data is from your database
set_value('name', $data['name'])
```

I used "name" as an example, but this could be any field in your record.

But back in your controller, you'd want something like this:

```
if( $this->input->method == 'POST' )
     // Do your validation and updating to the record

// Then pull in the record for your view
$view_data['data'] = $this->db->query('... ... ...');
```

By doing this, you're always pulling in the fresh data

Answer (score -2):

Your code looks pretty solid.

I would suggest to try adding a

```
$this->db->update(.......)
```

at the end of your function.

Then the database gets updated with up-to-the-second info.

Hope this helps.